# Usage of custom post types in a custom admin menu

Tags: customization, admin, admin-menu

This question is a little hard to explain but i will try to be as clear as i can:

I have a custom theme that i am presently working on, within this theme i have added a top level menu in wp-admin with 5 submenus below it.

In one of these submenus i wish to add custom post types where admin user can create and edit posts and not have to go through the default WP process of Posts >> Add New.

The reason i want to do it this way is that the custom post types will contain hooks to include certain calls to an API (user tokens, keys, xml etc) and i want to avoid the confusion of the end user creating posts away from what are to be core functions of my theme.

At present i have no code worked out, (im not asking for it either) as you may understand googling on the lines of "custom post types admin menu" etc just throws back all sorts of irrelevance, do any of you gurus have a pointer where i can get a heads up on how to implement this?.

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Register the post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) without a UI (`'show_ui'=>false`), then you will have to to create a form on your submenu page(s) and one or more handlers for those forms. [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)/[`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) can handle the post insertion if you give them the right information. Based on the information available, that is the best I've got.

For a custom post type, you'd never go to "Posts >> Add New", though. You'd go to "CPT-Name >> Add New". They are distinct menus.

Comment: thanks for the answer, was over a year ago since i last meddled with WP and post types, thanks for the correction too regarding CPT's.. much appreciated

Comment: should this 'show_GUI'=>false be 'show_ui'=>false as i cant find reference in codex register post type to 'show_GUI'=>false thanks

Comment: Sorry, yes. That should be `show_ui`.